# Is $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$ a field ? where, $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ such that $\alpha + \pi = {\pi}^2 \alpha $

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

> Is $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$ a field ? Here $\alpha \in \Bbb C$ is such that $\alpha + \pi = {\pi}^2 \alpha $ .

I tried to argue by contradiction. Tried to come up with tricks commonly used for concluding that if $\theta$ is transcendental, then so is $\theta^2$, so is $\sqrt{\theta}$ and so on. But couldn't come up with a suitable one!

Any hint will be really appreciated.

Comment: $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{\pi^2-1}$. Your ring is a field iff $\alpha$ is algebraic. Thus, if $\sum_k{a_kX^k}$ is a polynomial with degree $d$ and rational coefficients with $\alpha$ as a root, then $\sum_k{a_kX^k(X^2-1)^{d-k}}$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients, degree $2d$ if $a_0 \neq 0$, and $\pi$ is a root.

Comment: What Mindlack said. Alternatively, the equation shows that $\pi$ is algebraic over the field $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. If $\alpha$ were algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$ then ...

Comment: @Mindlack Can I simply take any polynomial i.e. $a_n X^n+\dots+a_0$ where $a_0 \ne 0$ since $\alpha \notin \Bbb Q$ to have $\alpha$ as a root and thus, $a_n ({\frac{\pi}{{\pi}^2 -1}})^n+\dots+a_0=0 \implies a_n {\pi}^n+\dots+a_0 {({\pi}^2 -1)}^n=0$ and arrive at a contradiction!

Comment: Yes, but pay a closer attention to the powers of $\pi^2-1$.

Comment: @Mindlack Now,it's alright?

Comment: It is right indeed.

Comment: @Mindlack would you consider posting your comment as an answer, then I would accept you answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $\alpha+\pi=\pi^2\alpha$, by basic algebra $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{\pi^2-1}$. This is transcendental because $\pi$ is. After all, if $\alpha$ were algebraic then $f(\alpha)=0$ for some $f\in\Bbb{Q}[X]$, but then $\pi$ is a root of
$$(X^2-1)^nf(X)\in\Bbb{Q}[X],$$
where $n:=\deg f$, contradicting the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: ...and since $\alpha$ is transcendental, $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is not a field.